# Calendar.getInstance method not loading userdefined locale classes

Tags: java, calendar, locale

In JDK 6

I have implemented CalendarData_en_AT class for locale(en, AT) which is a user defined locale(not defined in jre). I see that when I try to load the locale using `Calendar.getInstance()` method it loads `CalendarData_en.class`

When further debugged, I found that it picks up only the locales that are specified in `LocaleMetaDataInfo` class

What needs to be done so that when we call `Calendar.getInstance(new Locale(en, AT))` it loads `CalendarData_en_AT.class`

Code below:

I have a class `CalendarData_en_AT.java`

```
public class CalendarData_en_AT extends LocaleNamesBundle{

    public CalendarData_en_AT(){
    }

    protected final Object[][] getContents(){
        return
            new Object[][] { 
                new Object[] { "firstDayOfWeek", "2" },
                new Object[] { "minimalDaysInFirstWeek", "4" }
            };
    }
}
```

The compiled class is enclosed in a .jar file and have been placed in jre/lib/ext

Now from my test class

if I call `Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("en","AT")).getFirstDayOfWeek()`

it should return 2, but as of now it returns 1, reason being it loads `CalendarData_en.class` provide by and not `CalendarData_en_AT.class` which is user implemented

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you can actually do this for the `Calendar` class.
You'll have to create a provider conforming to the Locale Sensitive Services SPI.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/naotoj/entry/about_the_locale_sensitive_services) by a Sun employee for further details on creating and packaging such a provider

Comment: I have implemented sun.util.resources.CalendarData_en_*, sun.util.resources.CurrencyNames_en_*, sun.util.resources.FormatData_en_* classes for user defined locale , Implemented CurrencyNameProvider to call the sun.util.resources.CurrencyNames_en_* class, Implemented DecimalFormatSymbolsProvider calls the sun.util.resources.FormatData_en_* class, but could'nt find a provider that could call sun.util.resources.CalendarData_en_* classes